# How to find more accurate numerical integration result using Richardson's Extrapolation given midpoint and trapezoidal conditions?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, extrapolation

[image]
This question has been confusing me. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You would need to give a little more detail, it is not clear how extrapolation is connected to your values. Btw, trapezoidal with Richardson extrapolation comes out as Simpson integration.

Comment: @LutzL, to be precise, Simpson is only the result of one stage of extrapolating the trapezoidal rule; it is Romberg quadrature that corresponds to the full course.

Comment: Megann, can you mention the textbook where you got this problem? As it stands, any context useful for solving that is not in the screenshot you provided.

Comment: No textbook! Its part of an online practice quiz for my numerical methods class.  This is the whole question with no more details, hence my confusion.